# Using SoundCloud API for Android

Tags: java, android, soundcloud

I am trying to integrate SoundCloud into my app.
I want to specifically make a list of few playlist available in my app (and playable).

I seached anywhere without any result.
Then I found https://github.com/chemalarrea/soundcloudapi-android.
The problem is that I am not sure how to use it.
Imported it to my project, and wrote a few lines.

```
public void getSoundCloudplaylist() {
    final ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

    //DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);

    Call<List<Track>> call = Soundroid.getSoundcloudService().searchTracksByTags("JiwakuBermazmur", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Track>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Track>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccess()) {
                listItems.addAll(response.body());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }

    });
```

[image]

I am a super newbie, by the way.
Do apologize for any mistake.
And as I am not even sure how to continue anyway, any help is greatly  appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

change your `ListItems` to

```
final ArrayList<Track> listItems=new ArrayList<Track>();
```